# Setting multiple instances for Verticles using vertx embedded and Guice

Tags: java, guice, inject, vert.x

I am using Vertx cluster on the same machine(dev mode). 
I am using guice to Inject some pojo's as well.

However when I try to increase Verticle instances I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't specify > 1 instances for already created verticle
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:70)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:516)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:511)
    at com.mycompany.world_map_service.web.starter.StarterVerticle.lambda$main$0(StarterVerticle.java:39)
```

This is How I configure it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StarterVerticle.class);


        ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager();
        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);
        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
            DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config);
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                Vertx vertx = res.result();
                //  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector(vertx));
                Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector(vertx, deploymentOptions));
                vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(VertxHttpServerVerticle.class), deploymentOptions.setInstances(3));
                ...
}
```

Thats my AppInjector class:

```
public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {

    private Vertx vertx = null;
    private Context context = null;
    DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = null;


    public AppInjector(Vertx vertx, DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions) {
        this.vertx = vertx;
        this.context = vertx.getOrCreateContext();
        this.deploymentOptions = deploymentOptions;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(LocationService.class).to(LocationServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(LocationServiceDAO.class).to(LocationServiceDaoImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(RedisRepo.class).toProvider(() -> {
            return new RedisRepo(deploymentOptions.getConfig());
        });
        bind(Neo4jRepo.class).toProvider(() -> {
            return new Neo4jRepo(deploymentOptions.getConfig());
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why I get collision ? 
I know that I should use by name: `com.mycompany.world_map_service.web.http.VertxHttpServerVerticle` but than if I inject dependencies they are going to be duplicated for each instance, won't they?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late here, but here's the "why" for someone maybe down the road that finds this question.  Follow the error message:

> Can't specify > 1 instances for already created verticle

You're creating an instance of the Verticle using Guice, and then trying to deploy 3 instances, but you've already created a Verticle instance:

```
vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(VertxHttpServerVerticle.class), deploymentOptions.setInstances(3));
```

This is why you want to pass the class name. You can see the flow in [io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.vertx/vertx-core/3.0.0/io/vertx/core/impl/DeploymentManager.java?av=f#86) which explains the above error as well.

> I know that I should use by name:
>   "com.mycompany.world_map_service.web.http.VertxHttpServerVerticle" but
>   than if I inject dependencies they going to be duplicated for each
>   instance wont they?

I'm not sure what you mean by this.  If you don't want to duplicate data/dependencies for some reason, perhaps you could involve another object, or singleton, or leverage [Vertx's Shared Data](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_shared_data_with_vert_x)?